# Relative import of a file that imports another file within same submodule

Tags: python

I have the following structure of my project

```
Project\
    Core\
        __init__.py (empty)
        indicators.py
        platform_core.py (which imports indicators)
    Tests\
        test.py (import Core here)
```

in test.py I have

```
import sys
sys.path.append(sys.path[0] + "/..")
import Core.platform_core
```

if I `import Core.platform_core` and run test.py, I get the following error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indicators'`

This doesn't happen if I `import Core`. I also tried

```
import Core.indicators
import Core.platform_core
```

but get the same error.

My question is whether it is possible to do a relative import of a file that imports another file within the same sub module, without import the whole sub module?

Edit:
In platform_corer.py, the code that imports indicators is 
`from indicators import SMA`

Comment: Show the code of "platform_core.py" that imports "indicators.py".

Comment: @MichaelButscher it's just ```from indicators import SMA```

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: Add an empty `__init__.py` file in "Core" directory to mark it as Python package.

Comment: @MichaelButscher version 3.7. Core has an empty init file. Still having the error.

Comment: Use `from .indicators import SMA` to make a relative import

Comment: @MichaelButscher jackpot. Can you post an answer and I will accept it? Also, Could you please provide an explanation why ```.indicators``` work, but not ```indicators```? Looks to me that python is looking for indicators in Tests folder?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I got another problem now. tests.py runs, but when I try to run platform_core.py, I get the following error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.indicators'; '__main__' is not a package```. Anyidea how to solve it? Do you know if I should expand this question or create new?

Comment: Best way to solve this is a start script in directory "Project" which in turn imports and executes "platform_core.py"